# pdf of X and Y for the tetrahedron

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider the experiment of tossing two tetrahedra (four sided die) each with labels $1$ to $4$. Let random variable $X$ be the number on the first die and random variable $Y$ be the larger of the two numbers. Show that the joint probability mass function of $(X,Y)$ is given by
$$
\mathbb P(X=i,Y=j) = \begin{cases}
\frac1{16},& (i,j)\in\{1,2,3,4\}^2\text{ and } i>j\\
\frac i{16},& (i,j)\in\{1,2,3,4\}^2\text{ and } i=j\\
0,& \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditioned on $\{X=i\}$ for $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, observe that
$$
\mathbb P(Y=i) = \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^i \{Y=k\}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^i \mathbb P(Y=k)= \frac i4,
$$
and for $i<j\leqslant 4$ that
$$
\mathbb P(Y=j) = \frac14.
$$
It follows that
$$
\mathbb P(X=i,Y=i) = \mathbb P(X=i,Y=i\mid X=i)\mathbb P(X=i) = \mathbb P(Y=i\mid X=i)\mathbb P(X=i) = \frac i4\cdot\frac14 = \frac i{16},
$$
and similarly
$$
\mathbb P(X=i,Y=j) = \mathbb P(X=i,Y=j\mid X=i)\mathbb P(X=i) =  \mathbb P(Y=j\mid X=i)\mathbb P(X=i) = \frac14\cdot\frac14=\frac1{16}.
$$